# Random seeking in external files using Flash

Tags: flash, video-streaming

I am working on a system that requires me to be able to load large video files using Flash. However, the problem I am running into is that users need to be able to seek to a random point in the file that may or may not be downloaded yet and have it instantly start playing (think Youtube). The video files can be hosted anywhere, and thus I do not have the ability to install policy files or anything of the like.

I have looked into this, and cannot find any answers. Does anyone know of a way to enable this random seeking in Flash files without policy requests or an RTMP server installed at the destination?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can look into.  First and foremost, I'd host your videos on CDN, they handle caching really well, and will make content downloads better for your end-users, especially regionally speaking.

Second, you can use the flash [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) functionality to both buffer and [seek](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#seek%28%29) to specific positions. There's several options for buffering, times, amount of data, etc..

[Full information here/link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html)

This should get you started in the right direction.

Oh, and one other thing you can look into (costs a lot more) is the Adobe Media Server:  http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does the NetStream functionality allow for streaming from external locations without requiring me to do some sort of set up to the external location? Currently, I am not hosting these video files myself, and they can come from various locations where I cannot configure the servers.

Comment: Yeah, you just specify the path and it loads.  You can even do this locally, if you'd like.  But you just have to pass the location in, and it handles the handshaking, etc..

Comment: I did a little searching on that page, and it looks like the type of seeking that I need would require the stream to be in what Adobe calls "Data Generation Mode." However, it looks like this will not work: "When you use this method without Flash Media Server, there are security considerations. A file in the local-trusted or local-with-networking sandbox can load and play a video file from the remote sandbox, but cannot access the remote file's data without explicit permission in the form of a URL policy file."

This appears to require configuration at the endpoint with policy files.

Comment: We use CDNs and load flvs/f4vs all the time with no policy requirements.  Not sure if that's different, but can attest to firsthand knowledge of it not being required for that practice.  Especially, if you're doing through an RTMP protocol.